# Proving that a language whose strings have prime length is not context-free

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar, pumping-lemma

Language is defined as:

$L = \{a \space | \space a ∈ \{0,1\}^*\ ∧ \space len(a) \text{ is a prime number}\}$

How to prove that this language is not context-free?
By far I was trying to prove it using the Pumping lemma, but struggled to find a suitable string on which to perform the proof.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I edited a language definition. a is a string that consists of 0s and 1s and its length is a prime number.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/217741/473276) answer your question? Technically it's slightly different but the size of the alphabet really isn't important here.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $1^p$ belongs to $L$ for any prime $p$. If $L$ were regular, then, by the pumping lemma, for large enough prime $p$, you can write $1^p$ as $xyz$, where $y$ is non-empty and any string of the form $xy^mz$ belongs to $L$. Choose a large enough prime $p$, and let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be the lengths of the corresponding $x$, $y$ and $z$ respectively. Then the length of $xy^mz$ is $a + mb + c$, which must be prime if $xy^mz \in L$. But as $b \neq 0$, the numbers $a + mb + c$ cannot all be prime, so $L$ cannot be regular.

Comment: I'm trying to prove that L is not context-free, not regular. I guess pumping lemma for context-free languages would be similar to the one you wrote above, can you clarify it?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. I think the same idea works to show that $L$ is not context free. I will update the answer when I have time.